# Return a BufferedImage based on the position of the image in a spritesheet

Tags: java, graphics, logic

Assume a sprite sheet has images (each 64 by 64), 
[image]

Now, say we have a method:

**public BufferedImage selectImage(int positionOfImage)**

The argument it takes; positionOfImage simply is just the position of the image. So say, I want the 31st position (that would be the smiley face on the sprite sheet above).

How would I go about doing this? My previous failed attempt used a 2 for loops:

```
    for(int row = 0; row <= rowHeight; row++){
        for(int pos = 0; pos < rowWidth; pos++){
                if((row * pos) + row == imagePos){
                    sprite = grabSprite(row * 64, pos * 64, 64, 64);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: A single for loop and the modulus operator? In fact, no for loop at all? Just a division and modulus? Show us your previous attempt.

Comment: [`BufferedImage#getSubImage`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#getSubimage(int,%20int,%20int,%20int)), you will need to know the number of columns before you can calculate the number of rows...

Comment: I'm not trying to calculate the number of rows or the number of columns. You could just do spriteSheet.getHeight() / 64

Comment: @Kayaman I've added the previous attempt. The reason why it worked (sometimes it returned the correct image, and other times it didn't) was obscure to me at the time of execution, though it's because the row * pos + row doesn't always give you what you want as there could be other multiples..